# cyberneko html settings to ignore unencoded greater than and less than symbol

Tags: java, cyberneko

I'm having htmlcontent which contains greater than and less than symbol. But those symbols are not encoded as &lt; and &gt;. To balance tags in the content i pass the content through cyberneko html parser. After parsing content in between those greater than and less than symbol are discared. To overcome this problem, what settings i have to set up in the cyberneko html parser?

**sample content:**

> <div>Average Response Time
>   server is critical because its value
>   282 > 0 ms. <br>[Threshold
>   Details : Critical if value > 0,
>   Warning if value = 0, Clear if value <
>   0]</div>

**After nekohtml parsing**

> <div><br> 0]</div>

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The program below will output

<div>Average Response Time server is critical because its value 282 &gt; 0 ms. <br/>[Threshold Details : Critical if value &gt; 0, Warning if value = 0, Clear if value &lt; 0]</div>

```
package test;

import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.apache.xerces.dom.DocumentImpl;
import org.cyberneko.html.parsers.DOMFragmentParser;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.DocumentFragment;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class TestHTMLDOMFragment {
    private static final String PARSE_TEXT = "<div>Average Response Time server is critical because its value 282 > 0 ms. <br>[Threshold Details : Critical if value > 0, Warning if value = 0, Clear if value < 0]</div>";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        DOMFragmentParser parser = new DOMFragmentParser();

        // output the elements in lowercase, nekohtml doesn't do this by default
        parser.setProperty("http://cyberneko.org/html/properties/names/elems","lower");

        // if this is set to true (the default, you dont need to specifiy this)
        // then neko html wont and an html,head and body tags to the response.
        parser.setFeature("http://cyberneko.org/html/features/document-fragment",true);

        Document document = new DocumentImpl();
        DocumentFragment fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

        // parse the document into a fragment
        parser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(PARSE_TEXT)), fragment);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        // don't display the namespace declaration
        transformer.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(fragment);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    }
}
```

The comments in the code above show the parser settings i've used.

I've also used the org.cyberneko.html.parsers.DOMFragmentParser as you *may* also be parsing text that is just an html fragment

I'm using nekohtml 1.9.14

If you use maven, here's the pom.xml dependencies section...

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```